# How to make reading the same file at the same time in multiple processes slow down the reading?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, file, file-io

I'm doing some research work on `Ubuntu 15.10 x64`. I want to study if there's a way to make 2 or more processes reading a text file simultaneously slow down each other's reading.

For example, two processes `P1` and `P2`. A text file `/etc/example.txt`. It has 1KB data.

P1's pseudo code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++) {
  str = read_file ('/etc/example.txt', 'r');
  print(str);
}
```

P2's pseudo code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
  str = read_file ('/etc/example.txt', 'r');
  print(str);
}

time = get_the_whole_run_time();
print(time / 100);
```

**Condition 1:**

`P1` is running. `P2` is used to "race" with `P1` and it calculates the average reading time **TIME_1**.

**Condition 2:**

`P1` is **NOT** running. Only run `P2` and it calculates the average reading time **TIME_2**.

My goal is to make **TIME_1** significantly higher than **TIME_2** (this is for research purpose). But my experiments don't work out that way. **TIME_1** is nearly the same as **TIME_2**.

I know there maybe are some things like file system cache that affects the result. I used the command: `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` to clear the cache. But it doesn't work.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It is highly likely **1 KB** for your data file will be entirely cached, i.e. *neither* will really stall the other.

Comment: Try 1GB perhaps. A 1KB read will be an atomic IO operation. No much chance of slowing it down.

Answer (score 0):

Use huge files to experiment.

Beware that if P1 and P2 run simultaneously, the average time may be less than with a single process; because one of the process may benefits of the fresh cache the other has set up just before, thus has no need to wait for physical I/O for example. Your experiment is very difficult to set up, as there is many many variables in it and many system-internal mechanisms that have non orthogonal effects; and surprising results may appear.